# Installing Ubuntu Desktop: Unable to install GRUB

Tags: grub2, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my approximately decade old Sony Vaio laptop. (VPCZ1 if anyone cares).

I downloaded xubuntu 16.04.2 desktop today and attempted to install it on the laptop.

I selected yes for all the default questions and selected to use the whole hard disk (no dual boot or anything like that).

After most of the installation has completed I get a message:

```
Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda
Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda' failed

This is a fatal error
```

I have searched for this issue but the only other people that have this problem seem to be trying to setup dual boot or have created the partitions themselves.

I have not done either of these things and the installation still fails.

I am installing from a USB stick.
My laptop does have a RAID in it but the disk is properly detected and if I reboot and use Ubuntu from the usb stick I can see that it has written files to the disk.

I have looked in the bios for any fast or secure boot settings but I couldn't see any, I think this laptop is long before those sort of features.

I have tried the installation a few times and always get the same result. I have tried with and without volume management.

I am fairly familiar with Ubuntu but to be honest I have very little understanding of the unix file-system or partitioning.

Comment: Is your disk partitioning gpt or dos?  If gpt, did you create a small 1-2M unformatted partition flagged bios-grub?

Comment: I don't know, I don't create any partitions, I let the installation create them all.

Comment: Change RAID to AHCI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to MichaelBay - turning off RAID sorted this.

I find it odd that the installed was able to copy some files but not the boot partition to the drive.

Thanks Michael.